# apt-get update fails to to fetch repositories

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

Trying to install packages on the new computer I got from Logic Supply.

When I first got it and logged in to install new packages, I did `apt-get update` and got (simplified):

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial InRelease
   Could not resolve 'usvt-livepaapt01.logicsupply.com'
Err:2 ...
Err:3 ...
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/xenial/InRelease Could not resolve 'usvt-livepaapt01.logicsupply.com'
W: ...
W: ...
W: Some files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

which is one problem, but the more serious one is that if I do (for example):

sudo apt-get install make

I get:

```
...
Package wget is not available, but is referred to by another package
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsolete, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'wget' has no installation candidate
```

I complained to Logic Supply, and they told me to just delete

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local.conf
```

and reboot, which I did. But it didn't solve it.

I have deleted `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Everything I can find on the web is on fixing the network, but my network seems ok. I can ping the `us.archive.ubuntu.com` servers.

The content of my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Any ideas? How do I reset apt-get not to try to resolve from the logicsupply.com server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like logicsupply left a proxy setting installed.

While it is true that all reference to a logicsupply domain was removed from `sources.list.d`, there is still a request for a proxy server through logicsupply.com in 
`/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Removing that http proxy server resolves the apt-get update issue.